# Why type deduction of function parameters are prioritized over the types from template?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

Lets have a look at the simple example of `enable_if` usages

```
template <bool, typename T = void>
struct enable_if
{
};

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T>
{
    typedef T type;
};
```

1. Here it is expected that `y` would be `int`, since `T` is our "enabled" type.

```
template <typename T, typename Y = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type>
void do_stuff(T t)
{
    (void)t;
    Y y;
    std::cout << typeid(y).name() << std::endl;
}
do_stuff(15); // int
```

2. But here things go somewhat non-explicit for me, and `y` will be deduced to whatever the type of the actual argument is going to be

```
template <typename T, typename Y = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type>
void do_stuff(T t, Y y)
{
    (void)t;
    std::cout << "do_stuff integral\n";
    std::cout << typeid(y).name() << std::endl;
}

do_stuff(15, 14.3);  // double
```

So my question is:

What could be the rules that forces compiler to prioritize deduction of `y` from the actual argument passed and ignore the enabled `type` from `enable_if` ?

Comment: That's just the way it is.  The compiler will always deduce the parameter if it can.  If it is only when it can't that it uses the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default template argument is used only when template argument isn't specified explicitly and template parameter can't be deduced. For this case, `Y` could be deduced from `14.3` as `double`, then default argument won't be used. Similarly, in the 1st sample you can also bypass the check of `std::enable_if` by specifying template argument.

```
do_stuff<int, double>(15); // double
```

BTW you can add non-type template parameter using `std::enable_if` in type declaration to make check taking effect all the time.

```
template <typename T, typename Y, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
void do_stuff(T t, Y y)
```